# Edit view on Django not displaying object into page

Tags: python, django

I got a form page to edit my objects from database, but when I access them with the edit button it goes to the url http://localhost:8000/acoes/edit/1, but I cannot see the object details in the form field. It is just empty as if I was going to create a new object (and it creates if I try)

Any suggestion? Every post and question that I found online states that the code would work being just like this, but it isnt.

on the template acoes_form.html

```
<form method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Gravar dados" class="btn btn-success" /> 
</form>
```

on views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def acoes_edit(request, pk, template_name='acoes/acoes_form.html'):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk)
    else:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    form = AcoesForm(request.POST or None, instance=acoes)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('acoes_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':AcoesForm})
```

on forms.py

```
class AcoesForm(ModelForm):

    #bunch of fields definitions
    #...
    #

    class Meta:
        model = Acoes
        fields = ['id_pedido','bl_msg','tb_msg','bl_shell','tb_shell','obs','ativo']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your view as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def acoes_edit(request, pk, template_name='acoes/acoes_form.html'):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk)
    else:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    form = AcoesForm(request.POST or None, instance=acoes)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('acoes_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

You were accidentally referring to the form class rather than the form instance.

On a side note you may want to only save the form if the person POSTed data to the view e.g.

```
@login_required(login_url="/login")
def acoes_edit(request, pk, template_name='acoes/acoes_form.html'):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk)
    else:
        acoes= get_object_or_404(Acoes, pk=pk, user=request.user)
    form = AcoesForm(request.POST or None, instance=acoes)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('acoes_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you! By what you said in the second code you are stating that it would automatically run save just by accessing the object in view? What kind of problems that would cause beside overloading the database?

Comment: Correct. Any request sent to the view (GET, POST, etc) would attempt to validate and save the form. If the data was valid it would redirect you if not the page would render with the form containing the invalid data. By explicitly accepting a certain method of request as shown above it will only perform that action when that request method is used.

Issues can include redirecting you when you get to the page and lots of unnecessary database writes which may impact performance.

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the last line, you are passing the form class and not the form object.

```
return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

Comment: That was a terrible mistake that I didn't realize. Thank you so much!